# Visual Basic Cursor

Tags: visual-studio, text-cursor

So I new to coding in VB and I am using VS Express in order to create a photography payment application for a client. Problem is I pressed something and now my text cursor has changed so that whenever I type it deleted the next letter.

Attached is a picture of what it looks like, I just want top revert it back to it's original text cursor.

[The Cursor.](http://gyazo.com/5a8704971a592510208307a189a6166e)

Thank's in advance!

Comment: this isn't a programming question.  but i would guess you've pressed the `Insert` key.

Comment: I know, I am sorry :( I didn't know where to go an ask the more simple questions, do you know of nay other site that can  answer basic programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you hit the "Insert" key. Hit it again and it should stop.